# Fanatic and Enthusiast badges

Tags: discussion, badges

Two badges Fanatic and Enthusiast have a criteria to

> Visit the site each day for X consecutive days. (Days are counted in
>   UTC.)

I'm here everyday, maybe not always asking nor answering. But I like to read about my favorite movies and shows, I read most of the questions and answers they get, sometimes I leave a comment or sometimes I provide my own answer.

Thing is, I'm here more than a year now. Can anyone explain how Fanatic and Enthusiast badges' criteria works?

For example, Enthusiast needs 30 days. So, do I have to come here every 30 days for 30 times?

Comment: As I recall, there has to be some interaction (voting/commenting) every day. Just visiting isn't quite enough.Perhaps check Meta.StackExchange for more details, I think it's there.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251762/how-does-stack-overflow-keep-track-of-visit-timestamps

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks :) anyway, I got 3 for this and I'm pretty sure that I was *active* more than 3 days. it's more than a year and I still got it as 3 days. I'm always logged in, could that been the issue? (I dun log out/log in frequently)

Answer (score 3):

> can anyone explain how Fanatic and Enthusiast badges' criteria works?

Enthusiast and Fanatic badges are awarded for visiting the site on consecutive 30 and 100 days respectively. As mentioned [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251766/4932070), what counted as a visit is not public, but from what I've observed, you have to visit home page or your [profile page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/51336/vishwa?tab=profile) or any post.

> Enthusiast needs 30 days. so do I have to come here every 30 days for 30 times?

Yes, you have to visit any page of the site including home page, any post etc for mentioned days to get this badge. But not for 30 times, just 30 days.

And yes you have visited the site for more than 3 days, but you miss one or two days every time. Remember, missing one single day will reset the counter. You don't have to login again, because it won't matter. What matters is your visit on the site.

Comment: does it affect differently if I visited using mobile app some days and desktop site some days?

Comment: Not at all. All you have to do is to visit the site.

Comment: Thanks mate, will try that :)

Comment: @Vishwa. Its important that the days are counted in UTC not your local time.

Comment: @iandotkelly maybe I visit few times during my day then :)